# Adding Web Parts to the Page Instance based on Page Layout using Feature

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am trying to add the Web Parts to Page Instance of the Page Layout using a Feature.I know it should be through **AllUsersWebPart** element .I could find the reference of adding a Default Web Part to Page Layout (**PortalLayouts** feature does it). Also I have seen same in **onet.xml** . I wanted to know if it possible to create an instance of the page based on the Page layout and add web part to it using the feature.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599228/add-webpart-to-default-wss-page-via-feature

Answer (score 1):

Inside a feature activation event handler ...

Get the Page to add the webpart (in this case - default.aspx)

```
SPFile thePage = curWeb.RootFolder.Files["default.aspx"];
```

Get the Webpart Manager

```
//get the web part manager

SPLimitedWebPartManager theMan = thePage.GetLimitedWebPartManager

(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
```

Then create a webpart instance

```
//add a new ThisWeekInPictures web part

ThisWeekInPicturesWebPart wpPix = new ThisWeekInPicturesWebPart();

wpPix.ImageLibrary = "Shared Pictures";

wpPix.Title = "My Pictures";
```

Then a Webpart Action

```
WebPartAction wpa = new WebPartAction(wpPix, WebPartAction.ActionType.Add,

"MiddleRightZone", 10)
```

And finnally add the webpart ...

```
theMan.AddWebPart(wpa.wp, wpa.zoneID, wpa.zoneIndex);
```

And it's done ... a new webpart in our page, I hope this helps ;)

For more informations please check this article http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/22/customizing-moss-2007-my-sites-within-the-enterprise.aspx